# An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Table' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Does someone know what this error 
(An explicit value for the identity column in table 'HD_AANVRAAG_FASE' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An explicit value for the identity column in table 'HD_AANVRAAG_FASE' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.) means? 
Any help is appreciated.

```
private void Insert2()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HELPDESK_OUTLOOKConnectionString3"].ToString());

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand dCmd2 = new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO HD_AANVRAAG_FASE VALUES (@fase_id, @aanvraag_id, @status_id, "
                + "@werknemer_id, @fase_datum) SET IDENTITY_INSERT HD_AANVRAAG_FASE OFF ",
            conn);



        dCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fase_id", 1);
        dCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aanvraag_id", 2622);
        dCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status_id", 15);
        dCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@werknemer_id", 165);
        dCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fase_datum", "12-12-2001");
        dCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What is the primary key of the HD_AANVRAAG table? aanvraag_id? And is it an identity column?

Comment: no, the primary key of HD_AANVRAAG_FASE is fase_id. How can I know if it's an identity column, what's that?

Comment: If you have an identity column, then you should NOT be turning identity_insert on and off in the application! There is a reason why this is an autogenerated number. let the database do it's work properly or take the identity off the table and create your own ids (Bad idea genrally as you can mess up data integrity very badly if you make a mistake). The ability to temporarily turn off identities shoudl only be used for the occasional migration of data and that is generally not done through an application.

Comment: Tassisto, if you don't understand your database table structure (of which identity is a part) then you have no business writing code to insert records as you are actively dangerous to the integrity of the data.

Comment: I asked my sql server specialist (because he's the one who made the database) what this problem is and he told me that I'm not allowed to give fase_id as a parameter. Because fase_id is autogenerated. That's what I did wrong!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you aren't specifying the columns explicitly, I assume `@fase_id` is being passed into an `IDENTITY` column, which **as the error indicates** you can't do unless you force it via `IDENTITY_INSERT`.

Usually, you let the DB generate this; specify the columns in the `INSERT` and ***omit*** the identity column (and don't try to assign a value). The straight after the `INSERT` your new id is available as `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying? :s :s

Comment: An identity column is a column with a **generated** value.  It sounds like you are trying to push values into it. That isn't how you typically use identity columns...

Answer (score 3):

Your code contains

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT HD_AANVRAAG_FASE OFF` at the end

But not a corresponding

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT HD_AANVRAAG_FASE ON` at the start

why are you explicitly inserting these any way? Is it a synchronization task?

Comment: @Massimo - `SET IDENTITY_INSERT HD_AANVRAAG_FASE ON` **isn't** in your code that's the issue. Either set it on if you have **an actual need** to insert explicit values or completely remove the attempt to insert to `HD_AANVRAAG_FASE` to get the automatically generated `identity` value.

Comment: That's not so kosher to turn it on/off. The thing is that I may not give it in the parameterlist.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT HD_AANVRAAG_FASE ON
```

before you run your insert. That's the exact cause of the error.

That said, inserting identity values explicitly is rare-- for example, used only when copying data from one table to another, or initializing a new table with explicit IDs. Usually you'll just want to omit identity values from your INSERT, which also avoids the error.

Comment: so I have to turn it off (which is even a worse problem) because I can overwrite data!